# Excel Image function - multiple uses in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use Excel's Image function to add many images in one cell from multiple URLs.

Something like

[image: this image of a person]

So I've tried using concatenation with

`=IMAGE("https://clipart-library.com/images/rcLndB5Xi.png")&IMAGE("https://clipart-library.com/images/rcLndB5Xi.png")`

And trying with `TEXTJOIN()`

`=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMAGE("https://clipart-library.com/images/rcLndB5Xi.png"),IMAGE("https://clipart-library.com/images/rcLndB5Xi.png"))`

Both end up with the #VALUE! error and I'm not seeing what the problem is, or if the Image function just doesn't allow for multiple images to be inserted period?

Comment: Does `LEN()` function works when you wrap to see the number of characters, dont think it will work, it will return `#VALUE!` error, those are images which are returned as output and _`placed in cell`_ and not over the cell which also doesnt work. Images are not text, while `TEXTJOIN()` is a function which used to combine multiple texts numbers etc bt not images. So it returns the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a new function:

```
Function IMAGE2(url1 As String, url2 As String)
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim pic1 As Picture, pic2 As Picture
Dim picWidth As Double

' Identify the cell that called the UDF
Set targetCell = Application.Caller

' Delete any previous images in the target cell
For Each pic In targetCell.Worksheet.Pictures
    If Not Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, targetCell) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next pic

' Import the first image
Set pic1 = targetCell.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url1)

' Resize the image to fit the cell height
pic1.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
pic1.Height = targetCell.RowHeight
picWidth = pic1.Width

' Position the image within the cell
pic1.Top = targetCell.Top
pic1.Left = targetCell.Left

' Import the second image
Set pic2 = targetCell.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url2)

' Resize the image to fit the cell height
pic2.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
pic2.Height = targetCell.RowHeight

' Position the image next to the first image within the cell
pic2.Top = targetCell.Top
pic2.Left = targetCell.Left + picWidth

' Return a string indicating success
IMAGE2 = ""
End Function
```